# Method BusListener.foundAdvertisedName not reached

Tags: android, alljoyn

I'm struggling with a basic AllJoyn implementation.

I registered a *BusListener* on the *BusAttachment* and overwrite the *foundAdvertisedName*, like

```
mBus.registerBusListener(new BusListener() 
{
  @Override
  public void foundAdvertisedName(String name, short transport, String namePrefix)
  {
  }
}
```

But when I call

```
mBus.findAdvertisedName(ServiceBusHandler.SERVICE_NAME);
```

it doesn't reach the *foundAdvertisedName* method.

What am I missing.

Comment: Can you please provide code for your BusListener class

Comment: It's the default BusListener from the alljoyn jar.

Comment: Most likely the name of the advertising service doesn't match the service name you are looking for